# In a dataframe in R, how can I create a column that combines whole numbers and decimals?

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have an example data frame such as:

```
> data.frame(X = c(1,2,4,0.5), Y = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1,0.9))
    X   Y
1 1.0 0.5
2 2.0 0.3
3 4.0 0.1
4 0.5 0.9
```

You will notice that the X column by default enters 1, 2, 4 as 1.0. Is there a way to have a dataframe that instead looks like:

```
X   Y
1 1   0.5
2 2   0.3
3 4   0.1
4 0.5 0.9
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn column `X` into a `character` vector:

```
library(dplyr);
df %>%
    mutate(X = as.character(X));
#    X   Y
#1   1 0.5
#2   2 0.3
#3   4 0.1
#4 0.5 0.9
```

Or in base R:

```
df$X <- as.character(df$X);
df;
#    X   Y
#1   1 0.5
#2   2 0.3
#3   4 0.1
#4 0.5 0.9
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,4,0.5), Y = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.1,0.9));
```

Comment: @user321627 If this answers your question, please consider [closing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by setting the check mark next to the answer.